# How can we use AutoCAD to create PDF from DWG/DNG files programmatically using Java?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, autocad

I am OK with any command line utility too. Basically I want to convert AutoCAD files to PDF using AutoCAD. I know there are several PDF virtual printer drivers that do this even without AutoCAD installed but I am looking at high quality PDF generation.

Thanks,
Nitesh

Answer (score 2):

All you need is Adobe Acrobat. See:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/X/pro/using/WS58a04a822e3e50102bd615109794195ff-7f35.w.html